# Netbeans and Git -- Workflow for non programming but related project files?

Tags: java, git, netbeans, github

So I'm fairly new to Git in general, and before I was using Dropbox to sync my files across multiple computers.  I am now using GitHub to track versions of my program remotely, and this is working great, however being that it's school related I also have other files that I am maintaining such as the PDF of the assignment and office documents related to the project.

When using command line git it is easy enough to initialize and track my entire directory, however afaik I need to use the command line version to sync to GitHub in order to maintain versions of files.  The easiest solution that I can see would be to continue using Dropbox to sync and keep my git repository in Dropbox, however if I am on a computer that I cannot use Dropbox on I will only have access to the programming files that netbeans tracks and would have to manually download/upload any other files that I want to sync.

So is there a pure NetBeans solution?  Or do I need to use a 3rd party Git program or batch script to do this?

Comment: I'd advise against keeping a Git repository inside Dropbox. I've had some errors (can't remember if it was outright corruption) occur because of the race conditions involved.

Comment: For documentation, you could look into using SkyDrive instead of Dropbox. It can view PDFs reasonably well, and the Office web apps let you do some editing from the browser as well. Git isn't really meant to handle non-text files well, but unless they're large and you care about the repository size you shouldn't get any issues. (For a school assignment, you probably don't.)

Comment: I've heard this as well, and my dropbox solution was working fine as far as file management went before I was taught git, so now I'm looking at how to use git and to also maintain a cloud synced document base.  Skydrive is a decent object, it would just be nice if I could use git to keep the non text files as well (depending on the complications you mentioned of git managing non-text files).  To clarify, I can use command line git to do this, but I can't seem to get netbeans git plugin to do this.

Comment: There aren't really any *complications* when it comes to keeping reasonably sized binary files in a Git repository. The problems come when you're actually collaborating on them - Word documents aren't really mergeable. Dropbox's solution is "don't even try" - if two people edit a file simultaneously, you'll get two files for the different versions and are expected to deal with the changes yourself. SkyDrive and Google Docs allow real-time editing of a document by multiple people, which is more convenient.

Comment: (None of this has anything to do with your Netbeans / Git setup issues. I'm just making observations based on what you've described you're doing.)

Comment: Yep thank you I completely understand, for files that I need to collaborate on it's important to use something like Google docs or SkyDrive.  In this case I was just looking to keep a file synced between computers for personal use without the need for Dropbox -- turns out my problem was I was using git incorrectly in NetBeans, I needed to select the git context menu from the project level rather than the package level.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans can handle Git perfectly. If the plugin is not installed from start, you can fetch it in the plugin center. There is no need to go back to the command line ever while using Netbeans, except for some very exotic stuff that you usually never come in contact with.

Comment: Doesn't handle ignoring the private project files automatically?

Comment: I have git working fine in Netbeans, however for any file that netbeans isn't working on I cannot get to sync up with github, I can only select the project files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured out how to do what I want purely in NetBeans.

If I simply make sure to initialize my repo with repository as the top level project name (the one with the coffee cup), then all files in that subfolder will be added tracked by git.  From there I need to make sure that when I do git requests from in netbeans I select the project first, otherwise it will only process the currently selected file (this seems like a dumb default).